# PHP xxhash extension calculate a large file

Tags: php, hash

I want to know how to calculate a large file hash value with xxhash like `md5_file()`. If I use `file_get_contents()` function to hold the file data then it cost much memory depends on the file size.

I use [this extension](https://github.com/stuartherbert/php-xxhash).

Comment: @jeroen I think he's talking about some third-party PHP extension that implements the xxHash algorithm. Google shows more than one, not sure which one he's using.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Sounds logical...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I use that extension.